# Grouping the NSArray elements into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSArray` some thing like in the following format.

The group array is :

```
(
    "Q-1-A1",
    "Q-1-A9",
    "Q-2-A1",
    "Q-2-A5",
    "Q-3-A1",
    "Q-3-A8",
    "Q-4-A1",
    "Q-4-A4",
    "Q-10-A2",
    "Q-8-A2",
    "Q-9-A2",
    "Q-7-A1",
    "Q-5-A2"
)
```

Now what i have to do is group the array elements some thing like this.

```
1 = ( "Q-1-A1","Q-1-A9")
2 = ("Q-2-A1","Q-2-A5",) ...
10 =("Q-10-A2")
```

can any one please help me how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
NSArray *array = @[@"Q-1-A1",
                   @"Q-1-A9",
                   @"Q-2-A1",
                   @"Q-2-A5",
                   @"Q-3-A1",
                   @"Q-3-A8",
                   @"Q-4-A1",
                   @"Q-4-A4",
                   @"Q-10-A2",
                   @"Q-8-A2",
                   @"Q-9-A2",
                   @"Q-7-A1",
                   @"Q-5-A2"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *string in array) {

    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

    NSString *key = components[1];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = dictionary[key];
    if (!tempArray) {
        tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [tempArray addObject:string];
    dictionary[key] = tempArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an NSMutableDictionary, then iterate through your 'group array'.

For each NSString object:

1. get the NSArray of componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"
2. use the second component to create a key and retrieve the object for that key from your mutable dictionary. If its nil then set it to an empty NSMutableArray.
3. add the original NSString to the mutable array.

Comment: It's coincidence that my answer looks like word by word to what you have mentioned. I could have never pen down the steps rather than writing the code. +1.

Comment: Was writing on my iPhone without access to a text editor, plus I prefer to explain 'how' so the OP can learn something instead of just cut & paste...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSArray *arrData =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Q-1-A1",@"Q-1-A9",@"Q-2-A1",@"Q-2-A5",@"Q-3-A1",@"Q-3-A8",@"Q-4-A1",@"Q-4-A4",@"Q-10-A2",@"Q-8-A2",@"Q-9-A2",@"Q-7-A1",@"Q-5-A2", nil ];
NSMutableDictionary *dictList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[arrData count];i++) {
    NSArray *arrItem = [[arrData objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSMutableArray *arrSplitedItems = [dictList valueForKey:[arrItem objectAtIndex:1]];
    if (!arrSplitedItems) {
        arrSplitedItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [arrSplitedItems addObject:[arrData objectAtIndex:i]];
    [dictList setValue:arrSplitedItems forKey:[arrItem objectAtIndex:1]];
}
NSArray *sortedKeys =[dictList allKeys];
NSArray *sortedArray = [sortedKeys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id str1, id str2) {
    return [((NSString *)str1) compare:((NSString *)str2) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
for (int i=0; i<[sortedArray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictList objectForKey:[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfYourMainArray/// Its YOur main Array;
temArray = (NSArray *)listOfYourMainArray; // Add Your main array to `temArray`.
NSMutableDictionary *lastDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; /// YOu need to creat Dictionary for arrange your values.

for (int i = 0; i< listOfYourMainArray.count; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0 ; j < temArray.count; j ++)
   {
     if (([[temArray objectAtIndex:j] rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q-%d", i] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound))
     {
         [lastDic setValue:[temArray objectAtIndex:j] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
     }
   }  
}

NSLog(@"%@", lastDic)
```